# what does the dot mean here in racket?

Tags: racket

What does the `.` in `(define-syntax-rule (id . pattern) template)` mean? Is it just part of the `define-syntax-rule` syntax or does it mean something special in racket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's standard variable arguments syntax for definitions (it's the same for procedures): all the identifiers after the name and before the dot are treated as required parameters, and after the dot comes a variable length *list* (with zero or more elements) with the optional parameters. For example:

```
(define (test x . args)
  (displayln x)
  (displayln args))

(test)
=> arity mismatch, the expected number of arguments
   does not match the given number

(test 1)
=> 1
   ()

(test 1 2)
=> 1
   (2)

(test 1 2 3)
=> 1
   (2 3)
```

It's possible to have zero required parameters, making all of the parameters optional:

```
(define (test . args)
  (displayln args))

(test)
=> ()

(test 1)
=> (1)

(test 1 2)
=> (1 2)
```

In the case of `define-syntax-rule`, this means that after the `id` zero or more patterns are expected:

```
(define-syntax-rule (id . pattern) template)
```